# Scientific word for organisms that can regrow themselves

Tags: botany, asexual-reproduction, regeneration

Is there any term for living organisms or more specifically animals that can regrow a whole from small components (assuming sufficient quantity of cells or specific organs are present)?  For example - as I understand - worms can regrow from a relatively small part of a worm - fragmentation?  Some creatures can regrow limbs.  Many plants can grown from small cuttings or root segments (fragmentation) as well as by budding.  I wonder if any term exists to describe all of these processes, either for the respective kingdoms or more generally.  In other words is there a class of life that is definitely not like mammals, which cannot reproduce limbs let alone survive the loss of any major organ function?

Comment: Yes, there is a term: This process is called regeneration.

Comment: …and you might describe the organisms as **self**-regenerating.

Comment: OK regeneration is clearly a related contept, but reading up on the term it's about biological processes rather than classification of organisms. Plus humans have some regeneration abilities. Perhaps my question is asking for a false dichotomy.